# Get stack trace of C# async calls using the API that the visual studio debugger uses

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, stack-trace, callstack

Is it possible to get an equivalent stack trace that is provided by the visual studio 2019 debugger.

Eg if I breakpoint in my async code inside of visual studio I see the following stack trace within the "Call Stack" window

```
    company.Common.dll!company.Common.Api.ResourcesDatabase.Lock() Line 58  C#
    company.Common.dll!company.Common.Api.ResourcesDatabase.ResourcesDatabase(bool openAndCreateDB) Line 29 C#
    company.Api.dll!company.Api.GlobalsDownloader.DownloadNewGlobals_UnderLock(System.Func<company.Common.Api.DTO.GlobalsType, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> reloadGlobals, company.Common.Api.DTO.GlobalsType globalsType) Line 124 C#
    [Resuming Async Method] 
    [External Code] 
    [Async Call Stack]  
    [Async] company.Api.dll!company.Api.ApiService.VerifyLogin_UnderLock(bool skipInitTasks, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) Line 1147   C#
    [Async] company.Api.dll!company.Api.ApiService.VerifyLogin(System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) Line 955  C#
    [Async] company.Api.dll!company.Api.ApiService.Init(System.Action initComplete, bool dontCheckForUpdates) Line 250  C#
    [Async] company.Editor.exe!company.Editor.ViewModel.MainViewModel.Init() Line 524   C#
    [Async] company.Editor.exe!company.Editor.ViewModel.MainViewModel.InitViewModel.AnonymousMethod__31_0() Line 331    C#
```

If I call `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1,true)` I get the following

```
   at company.Common.Api.ResourcesDatabase.Lock()
   at company.Common.Api.ResourcesDatabase..ctor(Boolean openAndCreateDB)
   at company.Api.GlobalsDownloader.<DownloadNewGlobals_UnderLock>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<OutputAsyncCausalityEvents>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<OutputWaitEtwEvents>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   ... 3 more layers of async
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.CompleteFromAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamAsyncResult.Complete(Object result)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult baseStreamResult)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.InvokeAsyncCallback(Object completedTask)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.System.Threading.Tasks.ITaskCompletionAction.Invoke(Task completingTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()    6.67s
```

The bit that I really like about the visual studio debugger is it can figure out what occurs before the async state engine.

```
[Resuming Async Method] 
[External Code] 
[Async Call Stack]
```

Eg the code before the "Async Call Stack". How does the visual studio debugger get this call stack and how can I get this in code?

I have tried the following nuget package which cleans up the stack slightly but doesn't help find the jump before the native code transition.

https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier

Comment: I don't know how the debugger is implemented, but I suspect it's a mix of enabling async debugging at the task level (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,217) and subscribing to the TPL event source (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs)

Comment: Yes it is looking likely that without actually attaching a debugger and the task being built with debug information it would not be possible to achieve. I don't actually need this but it would make tracking down bugs from stack traces easier.

Comment: These correspond to Visual Studio's Concord debug engine flags for a frame, eg `AsyncContinuationAnnotatedFrame` for [Resuming Async Method]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.callstack.dkmstackwalkframeflags Unfortunately, Concord is almost not documented. So, hard discovery work ahead if you really want to go that route https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Navigating-the-Concord-API Iron Python has example but they start the engine which is different: https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS

Comment: What is the Demystifier stack lacking and is it possible its due to how the code is being invoked? For example, is the stack trace you are looking at the invocation adjacent to your original calling thread thus you would need to find the other stack (if awaiting). Executing in Dataflow block vs. awaiting in a function show different stacktraces. The Dataflow has no context (usually of the source of queueing for execution).

Comment: What happens if you put a try/catch around `company.Api.GlobalsDownloader.DownloadNewGlobals_UnderLock Line 124 C#`. You can log the exception, and then re-throw it.